# Use a drop down list for activating a service

Tags: desktop-application, drop-down-list

Currently I'm designing the behaviour of a service into a SaaS; this service force the upgrade of the apps built with the SaaS platform

I have a drop-down list with existing versions (1.0 - 1.1 - 1.2) of the app and I have a toggle to activate / inactivate the service force update.

The developer team wants to remove this toggle in order to trigger the activation directly selecting the number version from the drop-down list.
Using modals, I manage the confirmation/cancel the action (activate force update/inactivate force update)

My questions are :
. This behaviour could be adapted to the use? Does this choice weird in UX ?

- To manage the case : inactivate service, I will add a element "inactivate" into the drop-down list. Is it a good practice?

---

[image]

Image above, e.g. I selected an Android number version of drop-down list. This selection launch a confirm /cancel window (image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that the developers' idea of removing the toggle button to force updates is the right usability improvement.

**The toggle button is used for delivering immediate results.**
If the user clicks the toggle, the system will immediately initiate the update.
This interaction breaks [Jakob's law](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/) because your system update should be initiated as other system updates  (most often the update is triggered by a button)

Selecting an update version (e.g., 1.1) and a confirmation of updating button is a common interaction and a good improvement.

**More about Toggle:**

1. [Stop Misusing Toggle Switches](https://uxmovement.com/mobile/stop-misusing-toggle-switches/)
2. [Toggle-Switch Guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/toggle-switch-guidelines/)

Answer (score 0):

The common behavior of a dropdown is when you select an option, the selected choice appears on the dropdown input field. This gives feedback to the user that the choice they selected is registered in the field. Having a modal window dialog suddenly popup, when you select a choice in a dropdown, isn't a common pattern and would feel rather disruptive to the user's mental flow, unless you have some sort of a well-designed transition/feedback. You could have like an 'Upgrade' button after the dropdown choice is selected. Or maybe show the available versions as little cards upfront on the page instead of choices hidden in a dropdown. Just suggestions on the top of my mind, of course i dont have the full context here.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about add a button but the label of this button should serves to activate or inactivate the service (automatic update). If this button has a different label according to the action (activate or inactivate) ?

Answer (score 0):

Related the provided mockups just one small improvement needs,
Please add a `Confirm button` under the drop down.
By clicking confirm button should appear the confirmation pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown lists are used to perform selections. These selections are later confirmed/submitted by various "Submit" buttons. It is extremely unusual to trigger an action using a dropdown list (therefore it violates users' expectations and should generally be avoided). It is even worse to have a dropdown list pop a modal - because the modal hides the dropdown, disorienting the users and preventing them from getting feedback about the completion of the dropdown selection. They basically don't see the dropdown closing with the selected option, because the UI interrupts their flow with the modal. The simplest and the most standard UI (K.I.S.S.) would be to have the dropdown perform the selection and the trigger the action via a regular button.